# Can a template specialization affect a variable it does not specialize?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a c++ class template which contains a couple of static variables, which I wish to specialize for various different values in an enum. Each specialization is declared in its own header file, and defined in its own source file (side note -- is this problematic? Would it be better to declare all the specializations in the template's header file, and define them all in the associated source file?)

I have two strings, `defaultName` and `name`, that I'd like to initialize to the same value as each other for each specialization, and for the unspecialized case. In the unspecialized case, I give `defaultName` its default value, and assign `name` the value of `defaultName`: `template<Spec S> std::string MyClass<S>::name = defaultName;`. The only way I can see of doing the same for all  is to duplicate this initialization in each of my specializations (e.g. `template<> std::string MyClass<A>::name = defaultName;`). It seems to me that it would be more convenient if there were a way of applying the unspecialized case `template<Spec S> std::string MyClass<S>::name = defaultName;` in the absence of a more specific initialization for `name`.

Stripping out the unrelated code and neglecting include guards, here's what it looks like. Specialization for `A` produces the unexpected behaviour, while specialization for `B` (as well as the unspecialized `C`) produces the expected behaviour.

```
/* MyClass.hh */

enum Spec{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

template <Spec S> class MyClass{
    private:
        const static std::string defaultName;
        static std::string name;
        
    public:
        MyClass<S>() {};
        
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const MyClass<S>& obj){
            return out << obj.defaultName << ": " << obj.name;
        }
        
        static void changeName(const std::string& newName){
            name = newName;
        }
};

template<Spec S> const std::string MyClass<S>::defaultName = "default";

template<Spec S> std::string MyClass<S>::name = defaultName;
```

```
/* A.hh -- first specialization */
#include "MyClass.hh"
#include <string>

template<> const std::string MyClass<A>::defaultName;
```

```
/* A.cc -- first specialization, definition */
#include "A.hh"

template<> const std::string MyClass<A>::defaultName = "A";
```

```
/* B.hh -- second specialization */
#include "MyClass.hh"
#include <string>

template<> const std::string MyClass<B>::defaultName;

template<> std::string MyClass<B>::name; //adding this produces expected behaviour
```

```
/* B.cc -- second specialization, definition */
#include "B.hh"

template<> const std::string MyClass<B>::defaultName = "B";

template<> std::string MyClass<B>::name = defaultName; //adding this produces expected behaviour
```

```
/* main.cc */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "MyClass.hh"
#include "A.hh"
#include "B.hh"

int main() {
    std::cout << MyClass<A>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << MyClass<B>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << MyClass<C>() << std::endl;
    
    MyClass<A>::changeName("A2");
    MyClass<B>::changeName("B2");
    MyClass<C>::changeName("C2");
    
    std::cout << MyClass<A>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << MyClass<B>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << MyClass<C>() << std::endl;
}
```

What I would expect to happen in specialization `A` is to initialize `defaultName` to `"A"` using the explicit specialization, then fall back to the template for all remaining initializations, including initializing `name` from `defaultName`. That would
produce output like this:

```
A: A
B: B
default : default
A: A2
B: B2
default : C2
```

Instead, what I observe is that `name` for specialization `A` behaves as though it is an empty string, which I believe means it is uninitialized for my compiler (gcc 9.3.0):

```
A: 
B: B
default : default
A: A2
B: B2
default : C2
```

This strikes me as strange, because not only is `name` not being initialized from `defaultName` in the specialization `A`, but it's also not being initialized from `defaultName` in the unspecialized case. What's going on here? Is it just that the value of `defaultName` to use is ambiguous, and so rather than make a decision, no value is selected?

Interestingly, I no longer have the same problem if I move the contents of `MyClass.hh`, `A.cc` and `B.cc` into `main.cc`, the output is what I would expect. However, this solution won't work for larger programs, as including the definitions of `MyClass<A>::defaultName` in the header `MyClass.hh` leads to multiple definition linker errors, and moving the definition into a new associated source file `MyClass.cc` returns to the same behaviour I'm observing now.

Any thoughts on what's going on here would be much appreciated!

Comment: fyi calling a variable (that you wish us to look at)  `str` in example code containing lots of `std::string`s (and other uses of _"str"_ ) is very unfriendly to the search function.

Comment: *...defined in its own source file (side note -- is this problematic?* The only things you can define outside of a header are those that don't depend on any template-parameter.

Comment: @Ripi2 yes, I'm aware. `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<B>` no longer depend on any template parameters. That note is more asking: is it problematic to define each of these specializations in their own file, or should they all be in one big file associated with the template itself.
@RichardCritten Will edit the variable names, one moment

Comment: replaced the variable `str` with `name`, and `defaultStr` with `defaultName`, and some minor associated changes

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you give the `A` enum a non-zero value, like `enum Spec { A=1, B, C};`?

Comment: @AdrianMole exactly the same behaviour (at least, in the posted configuration). It also doesn't matter which of the enum values are specialized for `name` and `defaultName` or `defaultName` only. Any specialization that does not explicitly give a value to `name` leaves it uninitialized.